# C, scanf(), сочетание набора сканируемых символов с максимальной длиной строки

Tags: c, scanf

Мне необходимо организовать считывание из потока ввода строк, ограничить длину и в роли разделителя использовать перевод строки.

Насколько я помню, в **C++** есть **getline()**, который позволяет задать разделитель, чтобы, например, одной строкой считалось несколько слов с пробелами между ними.

Найти что-то подобное для языка **C** мне не удалось.

Я хочу использовать что-то вроде:

```
// Считываем строку, пока не встретится '\n' или пока
// не считаем 20 символов.
scanf("%20[^\n]s", str);
```

Это правильная запись?

Мне не удалось найти нормальную документацию по смешиванию в одном спецификаторе *набора сканируемых символов* и *предела количества сканируемых символов*.

Подскажите, где можно найти эту информацию? У меня есть несколько книг, в том числе по **C11, C. Прата**, и там нет ни слова о рассматриваемом вопросе.

Comment: Нет, это не правильная запись. Что делает `s` в формате `"%20[^\n]s"`? Откуда берется это странная распространенное верование, что после `%[]` нужно писать `s`?

Comment: А нормальная докуметация - [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых,

```
scanf("%20[^\n]", str);
```

Никакого `s` там быть не должно. `%[]` - это самостоятельный спецификатор формата, никакого отношения к формату `%s` не имеющий.

Во-вторых, если разделителем является именно `'\n'`, то чем вас не устроил обычный `fgets`? Да, после него надо искать и удалять из строки замыкающий `'\n'`, но это не сложно.

В-третьих, проблема всех `scanf` вариантов заключается в том, они не умеют читать пустые строки. Если некоторый спецификатор формата не смог прочитать ни одного символа, то это считается неудачным чтением. Работа `scanf` прерывается с ошибкой, строка-получатель остается не тронутой. Ваш `scanf`, например, не умеет читать вход, который сразу содержит `'\n'`.

Comment: Если мой **scanf()** не сможет считать ни одного символа, то он вернет != 1, и я буду знать, что произошло.

Comment: @Максим: Да, но это неудобно. Пустая строка - совершенно штатная ситуация и обрабатывать ее через ошибочную ситуацию - странно и неудобно.

Comment: Ну в моем случае это именно то, что надо. Если не удалось получить имя файла, имеет смысл запросить его снова.

Answer (score 0):

Ориентируйтесь вот на эту справку: [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

В общем случае, строка формата выглядит так: `%[*][width][length]specifier`

Где, в качестве `specifier` можно указать либо `[^\n]`, либо `s`, но никак не оба сразу.